# Why "Grant admin consent" for delegated API permissions?

Tags: azure

I was following a vendor's instruction to create an Azure app in order that the 3rd party software can access all mailboxes in our tenant.

The instruction was pretty straightforward and it involves adding a **delegated** API permission for EWS.AccessAsUser.All using Office 365 Exchange Online.
What I don't understand is the instruction then asks me to **Grant admin consent** after adding this permission like below.

[image]

There must be some holes in my understanding as I thought delegated permission would require the user to sign-in to consent.  If the app does not want the user to explicitly sign-in, then it should set up an application API permission and then **Grant admin consent** to them.

So, what is the point of adding a delegated API permission and then Grant admin consent then?

Has it to do with the 3rd party software is accessing this Azure app outside our tenant?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of the [User Content Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?pivots=portal) set for your tenant, which if set to the default, allows users to consent for apps from verified publishers.

This is to help protect organization data from malicious apps.